# Как добавлять библиотеки в Dynamic Web Project в Eclipse ?

Tags: java, servlet, eclipse

Здравствуйте. Пишу сервлет службы, обрабатывающей POST-запросы с JSON-содержимым. Для парсинга JSON-объектов и их анализа требуются сторонние библиотеки с необходимыми классами. При добавлении в проект библиотеки стандартным способом (Build Path->Add External JARs, далее указываю путь на диске, все связывается..) и вызывании соответствующего метода, где используется некий класс JSONObject, выбрасывается исключение

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/json/JSONObject
```

При этом, однако и в коде и в IDE Eclipse все методы видятся, ошибок не вызывается. Почему же тогда класс не находится средой, при обработке сервлетом POST-запроса?? И как тогда корректно добавить в свой проект библиотеки для безболезненного обращения к их классам?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: кидать jar в папку WebContent-> WEB-INF-> lib; можно кидать через ctrl-c ctrl-v, можно простым перетаскиванием.

Comment: Спасибо, а то обошел проблему, вставкой всех исходников библиотеки (открытая, свободная благо).

Answer (score 1):

Бери и пользуйся, молодой падаван [http://www.findjar.com/](http://www.findjar.com/index.x?query=JSONObject)

Comment: Библиотеки на руках у меня уже есть.. Проблема в выбрасывании исключения, что якобы класса JSONObject и его производных нету в каталогах проекта. Это как я понимаю исключение и весь StackTrace. Прошу совета в этой проблеме.

Comment: вроде бы ее(либу) надо ложить в специальную папочку.. если нету - создать lib или посмотреть в нэте, как она должна называться в этом типе проекта